# Custom slide pager in BXSlider

Tags: bxslider

I am having an issue with custom pager in BXSlider. I am using version 3 and would like to call slides from outsite the slider. I know that I can do so with:

```
$('#go-prev').click(function(){
slider.goToPreviousSlide();
return false;
});
$('#go-next').click(function(){
slider.goToNextSlide();
return false;
});
```

I would like to link to also be able to call a specific slide: Ex:

```
$('#go-slide1').click(function(){
slider.goTo?????????????();
return false;
});
```

Can anyone help... I am very new at this : /

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go here http://bxslider.com/options and go down to public methods

I think you might be looking for this slider.goToSlide(3);